# Need wiring instructions for 2 pole thermostat, 2 heaters with two wall thermostats 240v

Tags: electrical

I am replacing a single volt thermostat with a double pole thermostat for the first heater and need to know how to wire it as there are now four wires.
I have red and black from panel,red and black from heater 1, and red and black from second thermostat in the box. TY.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

connect red and black from the panel to the red and black to the second thermostat and pigtail off a short bit of red and black. Then treat that red and black as if it's the only red and black from the panel.

Then wire like a regular thermostat with the red and black from the pigtail into the line side of the thermostat and the red and black from the heater to the load side of the thermostat.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought but it's nice to have it confirmed :)